# Finding equal subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given:

- a directed Graph
- Nodes have labels
- the same label can appear more than once
- edges don't have labels

I want to find the set of largest (connected) subgraphs which are equal taking the labels of the nodes into account.

The graph could be huge (millions of nodes) does anyone know an efficient solution for this?

I'm looking for algorithm and ideally a Java implementation.

Update: Since this problem is most likely NP-complete. I would also be interested in an algorithm that produces an approximated solution.

This seems to be close at least:
[Frequent Subgraphs](http://www.borgelt.net/papers/mlg_07.pdf)

Comment: Maybe that's just me, but I don't have understood the problem.
What do you mean by "equals"? That exists a bijective function f:Node_subgraph_A -> Node_subgraph_B so that, for each node a in A:

f(a) = b iff label_a == label_b ^ (for each x in out_degree(a), f(x) \in out_degree(b)) ?

Comment: Yes I think that's it. I want to find "redundant" subgraphs. At the end the graph would be partitionied into sets of "equal" subgraphs.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that's NP-hard.

Even if all the labels are the same that's at least as hard as graph isomorphism. (Join the two graphs together as a single disconnected graph; are the largest equal subgraphs the two original graphs?)

If identical labels are relatively rare it might be tractable.

Comment: good point, didn't see the relation to graph isomorphism. But yes the number of identical labels should be relatively small.